# Why can't we create a laser with wavelength of 13.5nm?

Tags: laser, optical-materials

I was reading about [EUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_ultraviolet_lithography) and the extraordinary process of firing two different lasers as tin droplet to collect 13.5nm wavelength light and I was wondering why this is required and we can't just create that light directly?

It would be helpful to understand what determines the wavelength of a laser and additionally why is it that firing other lasers at tin droplets creates that light?

Comment: Well, for a laser you would need one state some 90eV above another state. where you can efficiently drive it to achieve population inversion. Which requires a metastable state, i.e., one that has few other options to decay through. That will prove problematic in conventional laser systems.

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6595/ab3302 may prove useful. The 13.5nm emission is from highly charged Sn ion states, so you won't find them without a strongly driven plasma.

Comment: have you read about stimulated emission? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/lascon.html  . Have you had a quantum mechanics course?

Comment: Sez who?  [Here's a report](https://lasers.colostate.edu/extreme-ultraviolet-and-soft-x-ray-lasers-and-their-applications-to-nanoscience-and-nanotechnology/) of a laser at 6.9 nm.  Now for use in lithography you'd need a certain flux over a certain area at a certain place.   Hard to believe that there's no simpler way than the Sn process, but I know that a search for appropriate sources for EUV lithography has been going on since the 1970's at least.  so ...

Comment: @garyp - well, that is still a plasma-based gain medium, so quite similar to the Sn source.

Comment: @JonCuster I think there's a fundamental difference.  My understanding (crude) of the Sn source,  the radiation is produced by recombination.  In the highly ionized collision-pumped EUV lasers there is a population inversion and gain by stimulated emission.  Along the length of the gain medium intensity increases exponentially.

Comment: @garyp - I agree, but it is still similar in terms of needing highly charged ions with the right emission lines. Sn can't be run in the way the Ar tube is, so one could not make an amplifier with it as easily.

Comment: My first comment was directed at your first comment where you imply that an EUV laser is not likely to be possible.  They exist.